# How to reverse / invert / switch X and Y coordinates in OpenLayers 3+?

Tags: openlayers

In OpenLayers 2 you could pass additional paramater for layer options to reverse X and Y coordinates order in BBOX parameter for WMS GetMap request.

```
var layerOptions = {
    ...
    yx: {'EPSG:3346' : true}
}
```

How to do the same with OpenLayers 3+? I am actually using OpenLayers 6

Answer (score 3):

OpenLayers is aware of the difference in EPSG:4326 between WMS 1.1 and 1.3.  When using WMS 1.3 for other YX projections you should if possible use `+axis=neu` in the proj4 definition and then use YX order for that projection throughout your application so

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:3346","+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=24 +k=0.9998 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs");
```

becomes

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:3346","+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=24 +k=0.9998 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +axis=neu +no_defs");
```

If that is not possible (for example you are using multiple sources which support different orders) you would need to use a custom `imageLoadFunction` to modify the bbox in the image src url before loading it:

```
    new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: '....',
            params: { .... },
            imageLoadFunction: function(image, src) {
                var index = src.indexOf('?');
                var params = new URLSearchParams(src.slice(index));
                var bbox = params.get('BBOX').split(',');
                params.set('BBOX', [bbox[1], bbox[0], bbox[3], bbox[2]].toString());
                image.getImage().src = src.slice(0, index + 1) + params.toString();
            }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

After receiving response from Mike - a person who obviously has lots of knowledge about OpenLayers - and that response not being something like `"you just need to set this SOME_FLAG to SOME_VALUE and it will work just like that"` I went and wrote my own version for a function that returns WMS request URL that will be sent to server.

```
var source = new ol.source.TileWMS({...});

source.originalGetRequestUrl_ = source.getRequestUrl_;

source.getRequestUrl_= function (t, e, r, n, i, o) {
    var url = source.originalGetRequestUrl_(t, e, r, n, i, o);
    var bboxSepator = 'BBOX=';
    var urlParts = url.split(bboxSepator);
    var separator = '%2C';
    var bboxParts = urlParts[1].split(separator);
    urlParts[1] = bboxParts[1] + separator + bboxParts[0] + separator + bboxParts[3] + separator + bboxParts[2];
    url = urlParts[0] + bboxSepator + urlParts[1];
    return url;
};
```

Comment: It's best to avoid using internal methods not documented in the API.  A custom image load function is just as easy, I've added an example to my answer.